# setting tags with swiftmailer maligun

Tags: swiftmailer, mailgun

How can i set tags with swiftmailer using mailgun:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Hello Email')
    ->setFrom('send@example.com')
    ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'HelloBundle:Hello:email.txt.twig',
            array('name' => $name)
        )
    )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add them in headers :

```
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Tag', 'tag1'); 
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Tag', 'tag2');
```

More info on the doc https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-smtp